# Not able to access custom parameters passed to the jenkins build script

Tags: jenkins

I want to add some parameters from the web hooks into the mail sent from the Jenkins. I tried solutions provided in StackOverflow and elsewhere. No success yet.

I have the following in place:

1. Checked `This is a parameterized build`
2. The build script looks like `http://JENKINS_URL/job/android02/buildWithParameters?token=<My Token>&PARAM=<My Custom Params>`
3. In the mail content, I try to access the custom parameters by `${PARAM}`, `$PARAM`.
   [image]
   In the mail, however, I'm not getting the values I'm setting. If I set default values for `PARAM`, it is correctly displayed in the mail I receive. I tried `http://JENKINS_URL/job/android02/build?token=<My Token>&PARAM=<My Custom Params>` URL as well thinking just in case if it works. The mail is sent as `Editable email Notification` config.

Basically, everything is working except that I'm not able to access the custom parameters I have passed via `Trigger builds remotely` option.

Edit1:
If I keep a default value, say, `test` for the parameter, `PARAM`, in the mail received, I can see `test` displayed. But I need to get the value I'm passing in the build script.

Answer (score 1):

From the "tool tip" that you get when you click on the question mark next to "":

> ${ENV,var="VARIABLENAME"}
>
> Expands to an environment variable (specified here as VARIABLENAME) from the build environment. Note that this does not include any variables set by the build scripts themselves, only those set by Jenkins and other plugins.

So, use `${ENV,var="PARAM"}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, it didn't work. I added `${ENV,var="PARAM"}` to the mail content and still in the mail I received, it was empty. If I keep some default value for `PARAM`, then in the mail I get to see that value. I want to get the value that I'm setting in the script.  The tooltip that you quotes actually did say, *Note that this does not include any variables set by the build scripts themselves, only those set by Jenkins and other plugins* So does that mean I can't do it?

Comment: Really strange. Just so that I understand correctly, if you set a default value, the default value will be visible in the message. But when you trigger with parameter it's not visible? Are you able to access the value in a build step, e.g. is the parameter value available in a Shell or Batch script step?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The thing is that I'm pretty new to Jenkins build. I'll just mention what I doing. (1) The version control has hooked to  a python script to which it passes a set of information (such as last commit msg, committer, revision, etc.) . (2) Script reads required information from the step 1 and fires the build script by appending it to the `PARAM` queryparam (`http://JENKINS_URL/job/android02/buildWithParameters?token=XXXXXX&PARAM=blahblah`)  I don't know about the *Batch script step* you are talking about.

Comment: For the time being I created a file from the django script which calls the build script via URL and attached that file in the mail.

Comment: Okay, good that you got a temporary solution. The Batch script step I was referring to was the `Execute Shell` or `Execute windows batch script` steps that you have in free-style jobs. What job type do you have?